# Zillow's SearchResults.xsd and Visual Studio's XSD command

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, visual-studio, xsd

I tried to run Visual Studio's XSD.EXE utility on the zillow "SearchResults.xsd" to generate c# or vb.net classes but am having no luck and am looking for help. I keep getting errors (see below). Here is the original file I downloaded from http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetDeepSearchResults.htm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd"     
    xmlns:ZillowTypes="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd"
    schemaLocation="/vstatic/4/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd"  />

    <xsd:element name="searchresults">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>

                <xsd:element name="request">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="address" type="xsd:string" />
                            <xsd:element name="citystatezip" type="xsd:string" />
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>

                <xsd:element name="message" type="ZillowTypes:Message" />

                <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="response">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="results">
                                <xsd:complexType>
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="result" type="ZillowTypes:SimpleProperty" />
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>

            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

Here are the errors I keep getting when I try XSD.EXE from Visual Studio 2010:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents>xsd /classes SearchResults.xsd
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: Type 'http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd:Message' is not declared. Line 25, position 6.
Schema validation warning: Type 'http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd:SimpleProperty' is not declared. Line 33, position 12.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce
 incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'SearchResults'.
  - The datatype 'http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd:Message' is missing.
```

It looks like everything is defined in the ZillowTypes.xsd so I am stumped.

Comment: I know is not related to the topic but... just be aware Zillow limit the quantity of hit in their search through their api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with the setup. Starting from the location of the XSD file, which is supposed to be at http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd

The above XSD is referencing another xsd using an import with a relative uri `/vstatic/4/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd` which resolves to http://www.zillow.com/vstatic/4/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd - but this URL is not dereferenceable (404)!!

If instead you try http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd then you found part 2 of your puzzle, which is ZillowTypes.xsd.

Because of these errors, you need to download both XSD files to your local machine to fix them.

Download first as **SearchResults.xsd** and second as **ZillowTypes.xsd**; put them in the same folder.

Edit **SearchResults.xsd** by changing the line below:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd" schemaLocation="/vstatic/4/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd" />
```

to:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/ZillowTypes.xsd" schemaLocation="ZillowTypes.xsd"  />
```

Then you run into another problem. **ZillowTypes.xsd** contains an invalid element declaration! So edit the decl below:

```
<xsd:complexType name="investmentBuyingBlock">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="buying" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="rentalIncome" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="otherIncome" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="mortgagePayment" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="principal" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="interest" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="hoaFees" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="propertyTaxes" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="utilities" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="renovations" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="maintainCosts" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="homeOwnerInsurance" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="managementFees" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="advertisingCosts" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="otherExpenses" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="totalExpenses" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="opportunityCostInitial" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="opportunityCostYearly" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="depreciationBuilding" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="depreciationrenovation" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="totalBenefit" type="xsd:integer"/>
                <xsd:element name="totalProfitLoss" type="xsd:integer"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

To:

```
<xsd:complexType name="investmentBuyingBlock">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="buying" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="rentalIncome" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="otherIncome" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="mortgagePayment" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="principal" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="interest" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="hoaFees" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="propertyTaxes" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="utilities" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="renovations" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="maintainCosts" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="homeOwnerInsurance" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="managementFees" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="advertisingCosts" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="otherExpenses" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="totalExpenses" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="opportunityCostInitial" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="opportunityCostYearly" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="depreciationBuilding" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="depreciationrenovation" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="totalBenefit" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    <xsd:element name="totalProfitLoss" type="xsd:integer"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The re-run you XSD command line by replacing

`SearchResults.xml`

with

`SearchResults.xsd ZillowTypes.xsd`

It should work (at least the XSDs are valid now).

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Been looking at this for a couple of hours. I figured the first part out but I have no idea how you saw the second part. It was just complaining that the "sequence" element was bad. Never could find what that one was about.

Comment: If Zillow is looking at this. Please fix the crappy XSD files you are posting on your website. Doesn't anybody do Quality Assurance over there????